# Get sender email address when multiple mails are opened c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a c# add-in in outlook and I am trying to get the current recipient email address. If only one window with a single mail is opened the code bellow works. If the multiple emails are opened, the code bellow returns the last opened email address. Selection.Count is 1, even if I open 3 emails. Can you please help me?

I have also tried iterate them, but in the Selection, it is retrieved only the last opened email address

```
foreach (MailItem email in new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().ActiveExplorer().Selection)
{
    yield return email;
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] will be needed.

Comment: Surely you would want to iterate over the active mail windows, your code shows no attempt at this.

Comment: There is an example based on this on the MSDN website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection - you need to use the `Selection.Count` to get the number of items selected, and iterate through them with an index other than solely `[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Application.ActiveExplorer`, use `Application.ActiveWindow` and check whether it is an `Explorer` (use `Explorer.Selection` collection) or `Inspector` (use `Inspector.CurrentItem`).